# Andengine dynamic texture sometimes not loading

Tags: android, andengine

I am having problems with dynamic loading of textures.

When a user double taps on the screen, the background and other sprites are changed. There is no error produced, but some times the textures are cleared and new textures are just not loaded.

**This is my initial onCreateResource**

```
ITextureRegion BackgroundTextureRegion;
BitmapTextureAtlas MainTexture1;

//Initiate Textures
MainTexture1 = new BitmapTextureAtlas(this.getTextureManager(),1000,1000, TextureOptions.BILINEAR);

//Clear Textures
MainTexture1.addEmptyTextureAtlasSource(0, 0, 1000,1000);

//Assign Image Files to TextureRegions
BackgroundTextureRegion = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(MainTexture1, this, "Evening.jpg",0,0);

//Loading the Main Texture to memory
MainTexture1.load();
```

There is no problem until after this point. After this when user double taps or swipes the background, I change the texture dynamically. Here is the code:

```
MainTexture1.clearTextureAtlasSources();
    MainTexture1.addEmptyTextureAtlasSource(0, 0, 1000,1000);
    BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(MainTexture1, this, "WinterNight.jpg",0,0);
```

This usually changes the texture and I am getting the desired result. But in some devices (eg. Samsung Tab 2), 1 in 10 times the the MainTexture1 is cleared but its not loaded with new image.

So it just gives a black screen, how do I correct this?

Comment: May be you should reload texture again?

Comment: You mean MainTexture1.load(); again? Tried it.Now the problem is not often like it was before.but still 1 in 20 times it gets black.Thanks.

Comment: Haven't you exception in LogCat? Andengine sometimes hides it.

Comment: one of my device is not showing any problem, problem is in some other devices (samsung tab2 for example) now i am installing driver to see the logcat

Comment: No Logcat error found, there is no error, the sprite is just invisible,sprite get reappear if we take any settings or menu and closing it.

Comment: Try this example and check that problem reproduce with it:
https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngineExamples/blob/GLES2/src/org/andengine/examples/UpdateTextureExample.java

Comment: I had tried that example with in my app and i found that MainTexture1.addEmptyTextureAtlasSource(0, 0, 1000,1000); this part is making the sprite disappear, with out it problem of getting disappear is solved.but now sometimes the texture looks like a glitch(with artifacts) when i change the texture fast(only for like 1/10sec). thanks for spending time btw

Comment: I had a similar issue with the texture disappearing on my Nexus S and 2012 Nexus 7 but working on my Nexus 4, turned out it was because the texture wasn't a power of two, as soon as I made it 256x256 it worked on all devices.

Answer (score 0):

```
MainTexture1.clearTextureAtlasSources();
 //   MainTexture1.addEmptyTextureAtlasSource(0, 0, 1000,1000);
BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(MainTexture1, this, "WinterNight.jpg",0,0);
MainTexture1.load();
```

Try this

Comment: I had tried that as i told above, and the disappearing problem is solved, but now at some moment a small glitch is appearing like some garbage or some artifacts in the image for about 1/10 Sec.Now i place the MainTexture1.clearTextureAtlasSources(); in the second line and with addEmptyTextureAtlasSource on First it appears more good.But still sometimes when we doubletap fast sometimes that glitch is there.

Comment: Also i found that Commenting that addEmptyTextureAtlasSource() cause a little lag in changing background.So i rearranged the both.and still that glitch is there sometimes.

Comment: try by placing dynamic loading(i.e.loading new image..) data in Ui thread.And also make sure that all image  sizes are of less than the texture you are using

Comment: How that is done? well texture is 1000X1000 and image is same size.will that be a problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
      runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                MainTexture1.clearTextureAtlasSources();
   MainTexture1.addEmptyTextureAtlasSource(0, 0, 1024, 1024);
BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(MainTexture1, this, "WinterNight.jpg",0,0);
MainTexture1.load();
            }
        });
```

Like this.

If it is not working try with creating another textureatlas instead of same atlas.